# ブラウザ上で複数オーディオトラックのmp4のトラックを指定して再生できますか？

Tags: javascript, 動画

### やりたいこと

複数オーディオトラックの入ったmp4ファイルのトラックを指定して再生がしたく、
最終的にはトラック1をLで再生、トラック2をRで再生というようなことがしたいです。
ブラウザはChromeです。

WebAudioAPI を使えばなんとなくできそうだと思っていたのですが、うまくいきません。(ドキュメントの読み込みが甘いかもしれません)

下記で試してみたのはとりあえずトラックを指定してLRで再生させようとしています。

もしWebAudioAPIでできないのであれば、代案はありますでしょうか？

### ためしたこと

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="player" src=".test.mp4" height="300" controls></video>
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="track" data-track="0">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="track" data-track="1">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="track" data-track="2">3</button>
    <button type="button" class="track" data-track="3">4</button>
    <button type="button" class="track" data-track="4">5</button>
    <button type="button" class="track" data-track="5">6</button>
    <button type="button" class="track" data-track="6">7</button>
    <button type="button" class="track" data-track="7">8</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var player = document.getElementById('player');
      var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.WebKitAudioContext)();
      var audioSource = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(player);

      trackSelect = function (track) {
        var splitter = audioCtx.createChannelSplitter(8); // ここで8トラックに分けている・・・つもり
        var merger = audioCtx.createChannelMerger(2);

        audioSource.disconnect();
        audioSource.connect(splitter);

        splitter.connect(merger, track, 0); // L指定
        splitter.connect(merger, track, 1); // R指定
        merger.connect(audioCtx.destination);
      };
      player.onplay = function () {
        audioCtx.resume();
      };
      player.onpause = function () {
        audioCtx.suspend();
      };

      trackSelect(0);

      $('.track').on('click', function () {
        trackSelect(+$(this).data('track'));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: オーディオ・トラックの場合、`ChannelSplitter` ではなく [HTMLMediaElement.audioTracks](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks) を使うのではないでしょうか。対応しているウェブブラウザが少ないのですが、最新版の Chrome は対応している様です。

Comment: @metropolis  ありがとうございます。edge://flags/ から #enable-experimental-web-platform-features のフラグをいじらないといけないようですね。。。 できればそのようなフラグを弄ったりせずできるような方法を探しております。

Answer (score 1):

コメントいただきありがとうございました。
mp4ファイルからffmpegでトラックごとに音声を抽出し
トラック数分のaudio(video)タグを用意し、同時再生することで対応しようと思います。